# Was the snow globe breaking part of the plan?

Tags: plot-explanation, snowglobe

In the ABC Family movie "Snowglobe" was the globe getting broken a part of the "magical" plan in place for Angela's life?

There was obviously some kind of magic at play here, though it's never fully specified what it is, or where it comes from.

The lesson she is supposed to learn is to not take her family and life for granted, and to realize that her life and family's Christmas are already special the way they are.

Angela only seems to  realize this once she is trapped in the globe after trying to get Douglas and his "girlfriend" back inside.

In the process of sending them back, she herself gets sucked back inside and the globe breaks which prevents her from getting out. If that hadn't have happened, I assume she'd been able to leave the globe the same way that she had been all through the movie.

However, due to the breakage, she can only leave once she admits that her life may not be exactly perfect, but that it's special because it's *hers*. After admitting this, Joy and the delivery man (the very same delivery man that delivered the snow globe to her in the first place) help her leave the globe. This tells us that it was a set up of some kind, and that Joy and the delivery man had been in on it the whole time. But, again, this is never fully explored.